# python, post binary data from python2 to python3

Tags: python

I need to post some data to server from a binary file `AmbientTemp.dat`, and there is python2:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

fp = 'xxx/AmbientTemp.dat'
with open(fp, 'rb') as fo:
    ambient = fo.read(64)
data = urllib.urlencode({
    'action': 'xxx',
    'ambient': ambient,
})
req = urllib2.Request('http://xxx', data=data)
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

At first, I can save the data by python2:

```
class AmbientView(xxx):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ambient = self.request.POST.get('ambient', '')
        fp = 'xxx/AmbientTemp.dat'
        with open(fp, 'wb') as fo:
            fo.write(ambient)
        ...
```

But it is error in python3.5:

```
...fo.write(ambient)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

So, I encode the str data:

```
fo.write(ambient.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
```

But the `AmbientTemp.dat` become 78 bit, I just `read(64)`.

Comment: Are you looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html?

Comment: What web server framework are you using for `def post()`?

Comment: `def post()` is the method in a class, I use django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to encode the data with latin1, and get the correct data.

```
fo.write(ambient.encode(encoding='latin1'))
```